# Python & Scipy: How to fit a von mises distribution?

Tags: python, numpy, scipy

I'm trying to fit a von Mises distribution, from scipy (http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.stats.vonmises.html)

So I  tried

```
from scipy.stats import vonmises
kappa = 3
r = vonmises.rvs(kappa, size=1000)
plt.hist(r, normed=True,alpha=0.2)
```

It returns

[image]

However, when I fit the data on it

```
vonmises.fit(r)
# returns (1.2222011312461918, 0.024913780423670054, 2.4243546157480105e-30)

vonmises.fit(r, loc=0, scale=1)
# returns (1.549290021706847, 0.0013319431181202394, 7.1653626652619939e-29)
```

But none of the value returned is the parameter of Von Mises, kappa.

What is the returning value? Ifeel the second is loc, or mean value. But have no idea what the first returned value is.

And how should I fit a von mises distribution?

Comment: the returned values, in order, are `kappa`, `loc`, `scale`.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The returned values are kappa, loc and scale. Unfortunately, the von Mises pdf does not seem to yield itself to fitting. It does fit correctly if you fix the scale:

```
>>> vonmises.fit(r, fscale=1)
(2.994517240859579, -0.0080482378119089287, 1)
```

Comment: Saved my day! This should be put into documentation!

Comment: @cqcn1991 Some of it is in the [scipy documentation](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.stats.rv_continuous.fit.html#scipy.stats.rv_continuous.fit) :) . I have also tried to change the optimizer for the fit, but that doesn't seem to help.

Comment: The scale parameter doesn't make any sense for the von Mises distribution anyway.  The distribution is on a circle.  It can't be scaled.