# Python & Scipy: How to estimate a von mises scale factor with binned angle data?

Tags: python, math, scipy, statistics, normal-distribution

I have an array of binned angle data, and another array of weights for each bin. I am using the **vmpar()** function found [here](https://github.com/jhamrick/python-snippets/blob/873425de239a85219bf7b5ff6fe0b45bd0ee6940/snippets/circstats.py#L220) in order to estimate the loc and kappa parameters. I then use the **vmpdf()** function, found in the same script, to create a von mises probability density function (pdf).

However, the vmpar function does not give me a scale parameter like the scipy **vonmises.fit()** function [does](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39020222/python-scipy-how-to-fit-a-von-mises-distribution). But I don't know how to use the vonmises.fit() function with binned data, since this function does not seem to accept weights as input.

My question is therefore: how do I estimate the scale from my binned angle data? The reason I want to adjust the scale is so that I can plot my original data and the pdf on the same graph. For example, now the pdf is not scaled to my original data, as seen in the image below (blue=original data, red line = pdf).

I am quite new to circular statistics, so perhaps there is a very easy way to implement this that I am overlooking. I need to figure out this asap, so I appreciate any help!

[image: scaling wrong between original data and fitted von mises pdf]

Comment: Are you sure you want to use the scale parameter that is part of the SciPy parametrization when you fit your data?  That would make the fundamental period of the model a parameter, but in many cases, the fundamental period is known and fixed to be, say [0, 360] (if the angle is measured in degrees) or [-pi, pi] (if the angle is measure in radians).

Comment: Maybe I am just not understanding what the scale parameter does. Perhaps you can give a simple explanation?